# How to grep column after second pipe

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep, cut

Example:

```
3|100|test@test.com|0|0|6:1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,9|7:1,10,11,13,16,2,4,5,6,9|
```

Expected view after grep:

```
test@test.com
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`cut`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html):

```
$ echo '3|100|test@test.com|0|0|6:1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,9|7:1,10,11,13,16,2,4,5,6,9|' |\
cut -d'|' -f3
test@test.com
```

Comment: That's the Un*x spirit: small tools that do one task well. http://wiki.debian.org/TheUnixWay http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html

Answer (score 4):

Why grep? Use `cut`

```
echo "3|100|test@test.com|0|0|6:1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,9|7:1,10,11,13,16,2,4,5,6,9|" | cut -d '|' -f 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [awk](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/) is better suited for this usage:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ; { print $3 }'
```

If you have to extract more than one field from such an input, I think it is the easiest using awk.

(OFF: excuse me if I pointed in an *awk-ward* direction)

Comment: Maybe? Why do you think so?

Comment: Extracting multiple fields is possible with `cut`: `cut -d'|' -f3-5`

Comment: From my previous experiences, I assumed that either the poster, or someone else finding this page will face the issue that more than one column is required from the input. But a less complicated tool (cut) might be faster than universal ones (awk), if the restricted feature set of the lighter tool is adequate. (I don't have data to back this) Also, for me, the awk command is more readable. If I ever had to re-read the script written, I'd like to see the awk line in favor of the others - but that is just a personal opinion, not an objective fact. That's why only 'maybe'.

Comment: +1 Sorry, I had not done my homework on cut, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Just Imagine your content is present under this file `file1`

> [max@localhost ~]$ cat file1
>   3|100|test@test.com|0|0|6:1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,9|7:1,10,11,13,16,2,4,5,6,9|

To cut the `third` field use this command

> [max@localhost ~]$ cut -d "|" -f3 file1
>
> test@test.com

Here

> -d  : Specifies to use character | as delimiter
>
> -f1 : Print first field, if you want print second field use -f2, third field use -f3,  and so on...

suppose `file1` content is like this

> [max@localhost ~]$ cat file1
>
> root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

Then we have to use `:` as delimiter like this

To cut `first` field use f1

```
[max@localhost ~]$ cut -d ":" -f1 file1
root
```

To cut `second` field use f2

```
[max@localhost ~]$ cut -d ":" -f2 file1
x
```

To cut `third` field use f3

```
[max@localhost ~]$ cut -d ":" -f3 file1
0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's how you could do it with `grep` and `tr`:

```
<infile grep -Eo '^([^|]+\|){3}' | grep -Eo '[^|]+\|$' | tr -d '|'
```

The first regex grabs the first three pipe delimited fields. The second grep picks out the last field and tr removes the remaining delimiter.